# fail to read a file with fscanf

Tags: c, file

I ve written the following code, without any compilation errors nor warnings. But my program just crashes every time? Why and how could I fix that issue?

**the code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE *fp;

  int vertexIndex=0;
  float vertexTable[][2000]={0};
  int faceIndex = 0;
  int faceTable[][2000]={0};
  char lineHeader[128]={0};

  fp = fopen("C://Users//matt//Desktop//mannekeCoord.txt","r");

  if(fp == NULL) 
  {
     perror("Error in opening file");
     return(-1);
  }

  do
  {
    int res = fscanf(fp, "%s", lineHeader);
    if(res ==EOF)
      {break;}

    //vertex
    if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "v" ) == 0 ){
      fscanf(fp, "%f %f %f\n", &vertexTable[vertexIndex][0], &vertexTable[vertexIndex][1], &vertexTable[vertexIndex][2]);
      vertexIndex++;
    }

    //face 
    if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "f" ) == 0 ){
      fscanf(fp, "%d//%d %d//%d %d//%d %d//%d\n", &faceTable[faceIndex][0], &faceTable[faceIndex][1], &faceTable[faceIndex][2], &faceTable[faceIndex][3], &faceTable[faceIndex][4],  &faceTable[faceIndex][5], &faceTable[faceIndex][6],  &faceTable[faceIndex][7] );
      faceIndex++;
    }

  } while(1);

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

this is the short version of the content of the file it has to read:

```
  v -0.999718 -1.004708 0.999546

  v -0.932863 -2.122097 -1.108066

  v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000

  v -0.980325 0.671164 -1.031669

  v 0.094571 -2.805363 -1.376969

  v -0.437903 -2.617016 -1.306834

  f 728//48 782//48 785//48 751//48

  f 758//48 788//48 789//48 759//48

  f 727//48 783//48 782//48 728//48

  f 793//402 797//402 796//402 792//402

  f 790//48 794//48 797//48 793//48

  f 791//403 795//403 794//403 790//403

  f 783//404 791//404 790//404 782//404

  f 784//405 792//405 796//405 788//405

  f 789//48 797//48 794//48 786//48

  f 786//406 794//406 795//406 787//406
```

I compile it using this website: http://www.onlinecompiler.net/

Comment: Is there any online debugger also?

Comment: You will probably find it easier to debug this program if you **don't** use `scanf`.  Not kidding.  (There are a bunch of other reasons not to use `scanf` but for right now the important one is the debugging.)  (To convert text to machine numbers, use `strtol` for integers and `strtod` for floats.)

Comment: Just look at the `faceTable` and ask yourself whether the dimensions are a) of correct size, b) correctly declared, c) in correct order...

Answer (score 2):

Both `vertexTable` and `faceTable` are of size 1 by 2000, so you're writing to unallocated memory, which leads to "undefined behavior"

Answer (score 1):

These declarations are wrong:

```
float vertexTable[][2000]={0};
int faceTable[][2000]={0};
```

Instead you need this:

```
float vertexTable[2000][3]={0};
int faceTable[2000][8]={0};
```

I hope you are aware that you'll still run into problems if the number of vertexes or the number of faces exceeds 2000.

Comment: is a malloc really the only solution when I exceed the rage?